# Keeps on telling me that my code is not running all the way through What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

```
        print ('Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!')
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word[1:len(new_word)] + first + pyg
else:
    print ('empty')
```

Doing this in code academy keeps on telling me that my code is not running all the way through on line 8

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should get an error saying

```
Name 'new_word' is not defined
```

This is because you're using new_word before it even exists. Before starting the loop you can set new_word to word:

```
new_word = original.lower()
```

The other times it will use the last new_word.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `new_word` before you defined it (in the initialization of `new_word` itself). You probably meant to use `word`:

```
new_word = word[1:len(word)] + first + pyg
```

Also, you'd probably want to print out `new_word` when you're done, otherwise the program won't have any output for a non-empty input.